# Shader Not Working

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl

So i cant get my shader to render with color. My shader works when i dont set the color using the attribute Color. 
my code for vertex is:

```
typedef struct
{
   GLKVector3 Position;         //Position
   GLKVector4 Color;        //32 Bit color
   GLKVector3 Normal;       //For Lighting
   GLKVector2 TexCoord;         //For Texturing
} Vertex;
```

I have given the colors for all vertices as [1,0,0,1]
My vertex shader is this:

```
attribute vec3 Position;
attribute vec4 Color;
attribute vec3 Normal;
attribute vec2 TexCoord;
uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
varying vec4 DestinationColor;
void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix*ModelViewMatrix*vec4(Position,1);
    DestinationColor = Color;
}
```

And my Fragment Shader is this:

```
precision mediump float;
varying lowp vec4 DestinationColor; 
void main (void)  
{     
     gl_FragColor =DestinationColor;
}
```

And it Displays nothing.

It doesnt even work if i change the fragment shader to say gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1); Unless i uncomment the line in vertex shader setting the DestinationColor.

Please help i have been sitting on this for a while now

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with what you are doing. Are you checking the error log from your shader & program compilation?

Comment: Yes it completes without errors and runs fine

Comment: Try using the very same declaration for the varying in both shaders (do not use different precision qualifiers in both shaders).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this problem but i can't access my old account for bobjamin so I am using this new one. 
The solution was fairly simple.
Firstly i should mention that drhass' suggestion did help in that it allowed me to set a static color from the vertex shader and it would display however the problem was that the name Color must be a reserved keyword and its was causing problems.

The Answer was to change the attribute Color to SourceColor and everything worked fine!

Comment: The only reserved names in GLSL are anything prefixed with `gl_`, and a set of keywords and built-ins listed in http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf on pp. 16. There is either a bug in your software, or your platform is violating the specification.